# ¿ Transformar una fecha dada en texto? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Necesito transformar una fecha a un formato en letras, por ejemplo:

```
16/9/2020 -> "dieciséis de septiembre de dos mil veinte"
```

No he encontrado la forma de transformar la fecha en texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) para dar formato a tu fecha:

```js
const fecha = new Date(2020, 9, 16)
console.log(moment(fecha).format("DD [de] MMMM [de] YYYY"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.28.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.28.0/locale/es.min.js"></script>
```

y en caso que quieras ir más allá y pasar los números a palabras, puedes usar [`js-written-number`](https://github.com/yamadapc/js-written-number#usage).